# Alignment of buttons according to some condition

Tags: html, css, angular

I have to display a few buttons based on some condition. 
If the condition is true I need 5 buttons that are aligned(which works fine)
but when the condition is false, I need 7 buttons but with the same 4 buttons in the top and the next 3 buttons in the next line which should be aligned in the center. How do I achieve this?

The last three lines have If condition.

```
<div style="center-align">
<div class="styling"><button>1</button></div>
<div class="styling"><button>2</button></div>
<div class="styling"><button>3</button></div>
<div class="styling"><button>4</button></div>
<div class="styling"><button>5</button></div> 
<div class="styling"><button>6</button></div> 
<div class="styling"><button>7</button></div>
</div>

.styling{
 display: block;
      float: left;
      padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are expecting this to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides several ways to add classes conditionally:

```
1. [class.my-class]="condition"

2. [ngClass]="{'my-class': condition'}"

3.[ngClass]="(condition)?'my-class1':'my-class2'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use one or a couple *ngIf. From your question is unclear the disposition of button (if the condition is true are they 4 or 5? In the first phrase you say 5, in the next one 4) so I can give you a specific example, but if they are 4 something like this:

```
<div style="center-align">
    <div class="styling"><button>1</button></div>
    <div class="styling"><button>2</button></div>
    <div class="styling"><button>3</button></div>
    <div class="styling"><button>4</button></div>
    <div *ngIf="!condition">
        <div class="styling"><button>5</button></div> 
        <div class="styling"><button>6</button></div> 
        <div class="styling"><button>7</button></div>
    </div>
</div>

.styling{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```